# Finding the closest circulant matrix

Tags: matrices, circulant-matrices

I have a $N\times N$ symmetric matrix ${\bf A}$ containing only entries in $\{0, 1\}$.

Is there a method to find two matrices ${\bf A}^*$ and ${\bf B}$ with entries in $\{0, 1\}$ such that:

- ${\bf B}$ is circulant;
- $\forall i,j : {\bf A}^*_{ij} \leq {\bf B}_{ij}$;
- $\| {\bf B} - {\bf A}^*\|_1$ is minimal;

where ${\bf A}^*$ is a permutation of rows/columns of ${\bf A}$?

---

Let us consider an example. The following matrix is given:

${\bf A} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

There exists a permutation ${\bf A}^*$ of the rows/columns of ${\bf A}$ as follows:

${\bf A}^* = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Such that the following matrix ${\bf B}$ is circulant:

${\bf B} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

In that case, we have $\| {\bf B} - {\bf A}^*\|_1 = 2$, which is the minimum for all possible permutation ${\bf A}^*$.

Comment: How is $\Vert C \Vert_{0,1}$ defined?

Comment: @flawr probably the OP means $||x||_{0,1}$ is the number of nonzero entries in $x$.  Note that its not strictly a norm, but it can be useful.

Comment: That is right, just the notation for $\ell_0$ norm for matrices

Comment: Such a method exists. Since there are finitely many possibilities for $A*$ and $B$, you can try every of them and choose the optimal one. Of course, this is not a practical method, but I think it shows that the question requires some clarification.

Comment: I think this is pretty much obvious that an exhaustive search on the permutations and matrix complements is a solution... I was asking if some classical result exists, or if the problem is equivalent to some other problem for which literature exists

Comment: Can we relax $\ell_0$ to $\ell_1$?

Comment: I guess you can frame as a SAT problem, and have a SAT-solver solve it.

Comment: I guess in this case $\ell_0$ and $\ell_1$ are the same since entries are in $\{0,1\}$. How would you encode this as a SAT problem?